# StringTemplate Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory

Tags: race-condition, stringtemplate

Hy,

In my project I am using *Antlr.StringTemplate.StringTemplateGroup* class in order to create a localized template. I access the *.st* file and set the desired attributes as below.

```
public StringTemplate WrapValuesReportTemplateContent(   
   private StringTemplateGroup StringTemplateGroup = new StringTemplateGroup(StringTemplateGroupName);     

   StringTemplate stringTemplate = this.StringTemplateGroup.GetInstanceOf(path);

   stringTemplate.SetAttribute("atr1", value1);
   stringTemplate.SetAttribute("atr2", value2);

   return stringTemplate
)
```

The class is repeatedly used by a manager and due to this reason the following exception was triggered.

```
    System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithread applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.
   at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, Int32 dstOffsetBytes, Int32 byteCount)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
   at Antlr.StringTemplate.ConsoleErrorListener.Error(String s, Exception e)
   at Antlr.StringTemplate.StringTemplate.BreakTemplateIntoChunks()
```

I am quire new to StringTemplate and it's not clear for me how StringTemplates really work. From the error description I understand that the *.st* resource is not closed. And I have the following questions:

1. When creating a new StringTemplate we create a Stream for writing and reading to the .st file, or a new object where we modify the attributes
2. After a .st file is opened is it closed automatically once it gets out of scope
3. How is the best approach in order to avoid this error. We should use locks on the resources, or wrap everything in a using?

Any clarification would be very useful.
Thanks

Comment: Do you access the template from multiple threads?

Comment: Yes, it's a multithread application.

Comment: There is a more detailed answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915790/console-out-and-console-error-race-condition-error-in-a-windows-service-written)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try synchronizing accesses on the stringTemplate object.

My guess is that you will only need to synchronize if you are simultaneously modifying it and reading or modifying it. If you are just reading it, it doesn't usually matter.

```
    lock (stringTemplate)
    {
        // Access thread-sensitive resources.
    }
```

For efficiency reasons, you should keep your synchronized block as small as possible; just with the stringTemplate access.

Comment: This is the problem that I don't fully understand how it works. If I create a new StringTemplate and i use the addAttribute property I am writing this property to the .st file, or I am just modifying the StringTemplate object? I couldn't find any clear documentation about it.
For the moment a added lock(new object()){}  every time I use a StringTemplateGroup instance.

Comment: I don't think that lock code you wrote will do anything. Where did you get it from?

Comment: It was a suggestion from somebody. The object is not declared inside the lock. But indeed we create am object just to set a lock on it. I never considered setting the lock on the stringTemplate until now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've recently encountered the same bug!
Look at your stacktrace: it is thrown from ConsoleErrorListener.
To be short, the exception is thrown because of two threads are trying to write to Console.Out stream.
To eliminate this error You should override error handler for your template.

The solution which is marked as answer will work, but there will be too much lock contention.